# How to draw OpenCL calculated pixels to the screen with OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, opencl, pixel

I wan't to do some calculated pixelart with OpenCL and display this directly on the display without CPU roundtripping. I could use interoperability of OpenCL with OpenGL and write to the texture-banks of the GPU and display the texture with OpenGL. I was wondering what would be the best way to do this, since I do not need any 3d stuff, just 2d pixelart.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The best way would be to use OpenCL/OpenGL interop, if your OpenCL implementation supports it. This allows OpenCL to access certain OpenGL objects (buffer objects and textures/renderbuffers). You won't be able to directly access the default OpenGL framebuffer (ie: the display), but you will be able to access an image bound to a [framebuffer object](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object). From there, you can, in OpenGL, do a framebuffer blit to the default framebuffer. Nothing will touch CPU memory.

You'll have to look up the specifics on [CL/GL interop](http://www.cmsoft.com.br/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=99&Itemid=150) to learn the details however. The basic idea is that you create a renderbuffer in OpenGL (which you bind to an FBO). Then you hand that renderbuffer off to OpenCL, and do your computations into the renderbuffer. Once that's complete, you perform a `glBlitFramebuffer` to copy the data from the renderbuffer to the default framebuffer, then swap buffers to display it.

Comment: Good one. I know this method, but I have some problems with realization CL&GL interop. Can you please see my issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8789662/interoperability-texture-access-block?

Comment: I've written full demos of OpenCL/OpenGL/VAAPI interop that do exactly that: https://github.com/kallaballa/GCV